# How to iterate over a Julia dictionary?

Tags: loops, dictionary, julia

In python you can iterate over a dictionary like this:

```py
dict1 = {'a':1, 'b':2}

for key, value in dict1.items():
    print(key, value)

# -> a 1
#    b 2
```

How do you do the same in julia?

The closest I've found is this, but its not really optimal:

```
D = Dict("a"=>1, "b"=>2)

for a_pair in D
   println(a_pair.first, a_pair.second)
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do

```
for (key, val) in D
    println(key, ": ", val)
end
```

If you just want keys:

```
for key in keys(D)
    println(key)
end
```

For values:

```
for val in values(D)
    println(val)
end
```